# Ionic2 Beta is not creating app.bundle.js

Tags: angular, ionic2

I had run the following commands:

```
npm install -g ionic@beta
ionic start cutePuppyPics --v2
cd cutePuppyPics
ionic serve
```

It was working fine

I stopped Ionic

I made some changes in gulp file

```
gulp.task('clean', function(){
  return del('www/build/js');
});
```

Now my gulpfile is as follows:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    gulpWatch = require('gulp-watch'),
    del = require('del'),
    runSequence = require('run-sequence'),
    argv = process.argv;


/**
 * Ionic hooks
 * Add ':before' or ':after' to any Ionic project command name to run the specified
 * tasks before or after the command.
 */
gulp.task('serve:before', ['watch']);
gulp.task('emulate:before', ['build']);
gulp.task('deploy:before', ['build']);
gulp.task('build:before', ['build']);

// we want to 'watch' when livereloading
var shouldWatch = argv.indexOf('-l') > -1 || argv.indexOf('--livereload') > -1;
gulp.task('run:before', [shouldWatch ? 'watch' : 'build']);

/**
 * Ionic Gulp tasks, for more information on each see
 * https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-gulp-tasks
 *
 * Using these will allow you to stay up to date if the default Ionic 2 build
 * changes, but you are of course welcome (and encouraged) to customize your
 * build however you see fit.
 */
var buildBrowserify = require('ionic-gulp-browserify-typescript');
var buildSass = require('ionic-gulp-sass-build');
var copyHTML = require('ionic-gulp-html-copy');
var copyFonts = require('ionic-gulp-fonts-copy');
var copyScripts = require('ionic-gulp-scripts-copy');
var tslint = require('ionic-gulp-tslint');

var isRelease = argv.indexOf('--release') > -1;

gulp.task('watch', ['clean'], function(done){
  runSequence(
    ['sass', 'html', 'fonts', 'scripts'],
    function(){
      gulpWatch('app/**/*.scss', function(){ gulp.start('sass'); });
      gulpWatch('app/**/*.html', function(){ gulp.start('html'); });
      buildBrowserify({ watch: true }).on('end', done);
    }
  );
});

gulp.task('build', ['clean'], function(done){
  runSequence(
    ['sass', 'html', 'fonts', 'scripts'],
    function(){
      buildBrowserify({
        minify: isRelease,
        browserifyOptions: {
          debug: !isRelease
        },
        uglifyOptions: {
          mangle: false
        }
      }).on('end', done);
    }
  );
});

gulp.task('sass', buildSass);
gulp.task('html', copyHTML);
gulp.task('fonts', copyFonts);
gulp.task('scripts', copyScripts);
gulp.task('clean', function(){
  return del('www/build/js');
});
gulp.task('lint', tslint);
```

I added some file and folder to generate following structure

[image: dir]

Basically I added dashboard folder with some changes in build and typing folder

I again run ***ionic serve***

> My **app.build.js** and **app.build.map** is missing now
>    It gives 404 error

Comment: May I ask, why did you change the `clean` task?

Comment: Because I m putting some js and assets those does not come from src folder I want these in build directly.

Comment: But if you want to add resources there, you can just put them on `www` folder but not in `build` folder. `Build` folder content is intended to be completely deleted in each build, so if you place your assets in the `www` folder instead, it should be fine.

Comment: Yea, but what I'm doing wrong, Friend.

Comment: I removed it from build still it is not building. :(

Comment: So now your `gulpfile.js` is not modified anymore but it still doesn't build your app?

Comment: Right friend, Now my gulp file is not modified, still issue is comming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for it:

- In package.json changed the version of **ionic-gulp-browserify-typescript** to  older one "1.1.0"(current one is 2.0.0)
- run the command **npm i**
- rename the **index.d.ts** to **main.d.ts**

**Woohoo It worked**